# BL001 Component Parameter should have publi setter

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Solution Upgraded to Dotnet Core 3.1
I have found in this warnings, but my code Build & Run without problems.

I can't diagnose the problems.

I try to consolidate all packages.

How can I get details on the mistakes I make?

[Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unHV5.png)

Comment: This is a know issue with the Analyzers in the Solution Explorer.  It is a false positive.  You will notice the triangle shows on every Analyzer.  Don't worry about it. It is just

Answer (score 0):

This is a **"false positive"**. It is a known issue with the user interface of the Solution Explorer.

It has nothing to do with the upgrade and it is just a bug.

Here is the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/830127/visual-studio-aspnet-core-30-analyzer-showing-yell.html) issue.

Here is the [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/5418) issue as well.

It seems to be happening to a lot of people.

For me sometimes it goes away... but then after a while it comes back.